# What's they Key combination for the Compiz Grid Plug in?

Tags: compiz

I've installed compiz setting manager. I interested in winodw management section, grid plugin.
The short key for "put center" is KP5, i assumed that is Ctrl+Alt+5. But when I  using this combination nothing changed. The num is on on the numpad. What exectly should I press to move window to the grid? Thanks.

UPDATE: Maybe the problem caused by virtual machine? I'm running Ubuntu as guest machine. But another hotkeys work well.

Comment: Yes it is Ctrl+Alt+Numeric Keypad 0-9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Make sure the Grid plugin is enabled.

[image]

2) Click over the shortcut key combination and change it to what you want.

[image]

As our friend Uri Herrera said above, it makes difference if you use numpad keyboard.

Enjoy ;-)

Comment: I did all your steps but no success. I tried different combinations of hotkeys, didn't change the situation. How to be sure that grid plugin is enabled? I rechecked the "enable" check-box but again - nothing.

Comment: Are you running Unity or Ubuntu Classic? Can you try to logout and log back in to check if it is related to Unity?

Comment: I think it's running Ubuntu Classic, because virtual machine can't do Unity

Comment: What is the output of `compiz --replace`?

Comment: I think it doesn't work because of virtual machine, I've installed real Ubuntu and everything works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe your virtual machine lacks 3d acceleration then megacity is running instead if compiz.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're on a virtual machine. Do other Compiz effects work?

Some hotkeys are related to Compiz, but not all. The one that worked for you may have been a standard Gnome one.

Comment: for example Alt+F8 works, I think it's Compiz effect.

Comment: What does Alt+F8 do? Resize the window or move it?

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake it's Alt+F7, floating the window or something

Comment: That is a GNOME hotkey. I tried it with compiz disabled and it worked.