# my windows do not resize when I drag them on top or on side of my screen

Tags: unity, compiz, resize

I'd like to have them resizing automatically to half or full screen by moving the window to a border of the screen.
I use Ubuntu 11.10. Fresh install.

Comment: Are you using regular Unity, or Unity 2D?

Comment: I am using regular Unity, from fresh install!

Comment: [This  solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/60538/645490) worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to make sure that settings is setup in Compiz.  Here's how to do it.

If you don't Have Compiz Config Settings Manager installed you can install it by running the following command in a terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

You can then launch it by running the following command in the terminal

```
ccsm
```

You'll then want to find the 'Grid' Settings Option under Window Management.  Then if you click on the 'Edges' tab you'll be able to change the drop-down menus in "Resize Actions" to whatever you want to setup the edge-binding resize actions.

Comment: If my answer resolved your question please click the checkmark so this question shows up as answered.