# Windows not resizing when being dragged to the top or side of the screen

Tags: 16.04, unity, upgrade

I am unable to resize the windows when dragging to the top or the sides of the screen. Additionally, when dragging a smaller screen towards a corner (lower-right, for example), it does not line up with the edge of the screen like it used to (I can't cleanly place a program window in the corner of my screen).

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.2, and have been running it for a while. I'm currently on 4.4.0-70-generic, but this happened during the upgrade to 4.4.0-(63 or 64?)-generic. The change happened after I ran `apt update` and `apt upgrade` in the root environment, entering into such via `sudo -i`.

I don't see a difference in running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` as a normal user and `apt update && apt upgrade` as root, as `sudo` makes for a root instance. If there is an actual difference, that would be nice to know, as I will only run from the normal user profile then.

If any part of this is unclear, let me know, I can try to clarify.

Comment: If you open the compiz config settings manager (`ccsm` from terminal) is grid enabled? see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73782/my-windows-do-not-resize-when-i-drag-them-on-top-or-on-side-of-my-screen)